# Xcode (Obj-C) Updating a UIView (NSRect) after the window is already visible to the user

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit

I am fairly new to creating Xcode projects using Objective-C and i'm trying to make a simple 2d graphics program to show me how well my graphing code works before I implement it elsewhere.

I have gotten the drawing of everything right but the problem comes when I want to clear the strokes and stroke new lines. From what I see from when I run the program the view will only display what I have executed once it hits that @end at the end of the implementation. The issue with this is that by the time it hits the @end the code has already been run. and I can't figure out if I need to recall the class in a loop to update the view each time (or where or how to do this, perhaps something in main.m?) or if I need to call a function to update the view before it exits the implementation because right now all the lines are just overwriting each other before the user can see anything.

Here is the interface in my header file (connected to a UIView):

```
@interface GraphView : NSView
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;
@end
```

Implementation file:

Here is how I am creating my rectangle:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [self clearGrid:dirtyRect];
    [self drawLines];
}

- (void)clearGrid:(NSRect)theRect {
//Wiping the slate clean
[super drawRect:theRect];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
...
```

Here is what I am using to draw my lines:

```
NSBezierPath* eqLine = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[[NSColor greenColor] setStroke];
[eqLine setLineWidth:5.0];
[eqLine moveToPoint:NSMakePoint([self convertToPixels:previousX], [self convertToPixels:previousY])];
[eqLine lineToPoint:NSMakePoint([self convertToPixels:finalX], [self convertToPixels:finalY])];
[eqLine stroke];
```

I have been searching for the past few days now on how I could solve this but so far it hasn't turned up anything, perhaps i'm just not searching for the right thing. Any information is helpful even if it's just a point to a resource that I can look at. Let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that you're a noobie to this, which is not a crime. So there's a lot to address here. Let's take things one at a time.

To answer your basic question, the `-drawRect:` method is called whenever a view needs to draw its graphic representation, whatever that is. As long as nothing changes that would alter its graphical representation, the `-drawRect:` method will only be received once.

To inform Cocoa (or CocoaTouch) that the graphic representation has changed, you *invalidate* all, or a portion of, your view. This can be accomplished in many ways, but the simplest is by setting the `needsDisplay` property to `YES`. Once you do that, Cocoa will (at some point in the future) call the `-drawRect:` method again to modify the graphic representation of your view. Wash, rinse, repeat.

So here's the basic flow:

- You create your class and add it to a view. Cocoa draws your view the first time when it appears by sending your class a `-drawRect:` message.
- If you want your view to change, you *invalidate* a portion of the view (i.e. `view.needsDisplay = YES`). Then you just sit back and wait. Very soon, Cocoa will send `-drawRect:` again, your class draws the new and improved image, and it appears on the screen.
- Many changes will cause your view to be invalidated, and subsequently redrawn, automatically—say, if it's resized. But unless you make a change that Cocoa knows will require your view to redraw itself, you'll have to invalidate the view yourself.

Now for the nit-picking, which I hope you understand is all an effort to help you understand what's going on and improve your code...

- Your subject line says `UIView` but your code example subclasses `NSView` so I'm actually not sure if you're writing a macOS or an iOS app. It doesn't matter too much, because at this level the differences are minimal.
- Your `-drawRect:` calls `[self clearGrid:`..., when then calls `[super drawRect:`... Don't do this. As a rule, never use `super` except from within the overloaded method of the same name. In other words, `-drawRect:` can use `[super drawRect:`, but no other methods should. It's not "illegal", but it will save you grief in the long run.
- Your `-clearGrid:` method sets the `backgroundColor` of the window. Don't do this. The window's background color is a property, and your `-drawRect:` method should only be drawing the graphical representation of your view—nothing more, nothing less.
- You're calling `[super drawRect:` from within a direct subclass of `NSView` (or `UIView`). While that's OK, it's unnecessary. Both of these base classes clearly document that their `-drawRect:` method does nothing, so there's nothing to be gained by calling it. Again, it won't cause any harm, it's just pointless. When your `-drawRect:` method begins execution, a graphics context has already been set up, cleared, and is ready to draw into. Just start drawing.
- `@end` is not a statement. It does not get "executed". It's just a word that tell the compiler that the source code for your class has come to an end. The stuff that gets executed are the methods, like `-drawRect:`.
- In your `@interface` section you declared a `-drawRect:` method. This is superfluous, because the `-drawRect:` method is already declared in the superclass.

Comment: Everything you said makes complete sense, and I was looking at invalidation, but the more I look into it the issue seems to be that the window that has the `NSView` doesn't open until after the `-drawRect:` method ends and so all I am doing is updating a view that is in a window that isn't visible to the user yet. At what point is the window opened and is there a way I can open it manually before the end of `-drawRect:`?

Also, I really appreciate the extremely detailed response, it's people like you that help make the internet a better place.

Comment: As a rule, you never worry about _when_ `drawRect:` get called. Cocoa figures out when, and if, it gets called. It's possible that it can be called before your view is visible (so called "off screen" drawing), and it's very likely that Cocoa will not call `drawRect:` even if your view is invalid; screen geometry, overlapping windows, overlapping views, opacity, whether the screen saver is running, whether the display is in sleep mode ... all of these factors are considered. But those are Cocoa's worries, not yours. ;) You just write your `drawRect:` to draw your view and move on.